# separate between buttons click to initialize 2 models

Tags: java, android

I want to separate between two buttons click as when button1 is pressed the model1 is initialized and segmentation by first model will be shown on the screen and the same thing for button2 and model2 
the problem is : the 2 models aren't separated as the 2 models appear at the same time when any of two buttons is clicked.

**this is (MainSecond.java) where I initialized the 2 buttons:**

```
public class MainSecond extends Activity {
    public Button button1;
    public Button button2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_main);


        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainSecond.this,"b1c",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainSecond.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("message","hello");
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainSecond.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("message","hi");
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

            });
    }
}
```

**and this is my MainActivity.java where I take the 2 buttons click and initialize the 2 models :**

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buckyButton = findViewById(R.id.buckysButton);


    //  src_img =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.src_img) ;

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    // int intval=intent.getIntExtra("name",0);
    String message=intent.getStringExtra("message");


    if(message=="hello"){

        initModel();

    }

    else if(message=="hi"){

        initModel2();
    }
}

private void initModel() {
    new InitializeModelAsyncTask().execute((Void)null);
}
private void initModel2() {
    new InitializeModelAsyncTask2().execute((Void)null);
}

public class InitializeModelAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        final boolean ret = DeeplabModel.initialize();
        Logger.debug("initialize deeplab model: %s", ret);

        return ret;

    }
}

public class InitializeModelAsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        final boolean ret2 = DeeplabModel2.initialize();
        Logger.debug("initialize deeplab model: %s", ret2);

    }
}
```

and this is the most important code that is responsible for showing the models on the screen :

**SegmentBitmapsLoader.java**

```
public class SegmentBitmapsLoader extends AbsAsyncDataLoader<List<SegmentBitmap>> {

    private Uri mImageUri;


    public SegmentBitmapsLoader(Context context, Uri imageUri) {
        super(context);

        mImageUri = imageUri;

    }


    @Nullable
    @Override

    public List<SegmentBitmap> loadInBackground() {
        final Context context = getContext();

        if (context == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final Resources res = context.getResources();

        if (res == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (mImageUri == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final String filePath = FilePickUtils.getPath(context, mImageUri);
        Logger.debug("file to mask: %s", filePath);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath)) {
            return null;
        }

        boolean vertical = checkAndReportDimen(filePath);

        final int dw = res.getDimensionPixelSize(
                                                 vertical ? R.dimen.image_width_v : R.dimen.image_width_h);
        final int dh = res.getDimensionPixelSize(
                                                 vertical ? R.dimen.image_height_v : R.dimen.image_height_h);
        Logger.debug("display image dimen: [%d x %d]", dw, dh);

        Bitmap bitmap = decodeBitmapFromFile(filePath, dw, dh);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            return null;
        }


        List<SegmentBitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();

        bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_original, bitmap));//important note

        final int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        final int h = bitmap.getHeight();
        Logger.debug("decoded file dimen: [%d x %d]", w, h);

        EventBus.getDefault().post(new ImageDimenEvent(mImageUri, w, h));

        if (DeeplabModel2.initialize()==true) {


            float resizeRatio = (float) DeeplabModel2.INPUT_SIZE / Math.max(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            int rw = Math.round(w * resizeRatio);
            int rh = Math.round(h * resizeRatio);
            Logger.debug("resize bitmap: ratio = %f, [%d x %d] -> [%d x %d]",
                         resizeRatio, w, h, rw, rh);
            Bitmap resized = ImageUtils.tfResizeBilinear(bitmap, rw, rh);
            Bitmap mask = DeeplabModel2.segment(resized);
            if (mask != null) {
                mask = BitmapUtils.scaleBitmap(mask, w, h);
                bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_mask, mask));

                final Bitmap cropped = cropBitmapWithMask(bitmap, mask);
                bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_cropped, cropped));
            } else {
                bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_mask, (Bitmap) null));
                bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_cropped, (Bitmap) null));

            }


        }



        else if (DeeplabModel.initialize()==true) {


            float resizeRatio = (float) DeeplabModel.INPUT_SIZE / Math.max(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            int rw = Math.round(w * resizeRatio);
            int rh = Math.round(h * resizeRatio);
            Logger.debug("resize bitmap: ratio = %f, [%d x %d] -> [%d x %d]",
                         resizeRatio, w, h, rw, rh);
            Bitmap resized = ImageUtils.tfResizeBilinear(bitmap, rw, rh);
            Bitmap mask = DeeplabModel.segment(resized);
            if (mask != null) {
                mask = BitmapUtils.scaleBitmap(mask, w, h);
                bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_mask, mask));

                final Bitmap cropped = cropBitmapWithMask(bitmap, mask);
                bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_cropped, cropped));
            } else {
                bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_mask, (Bitmap) null));
                bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_cropped, (Bitmap) null));

            }


        }

        return bitmaps;
    }


    private boolean checkAndReportDimen(String filePath) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath)) {
            return false;
        }

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        final int width = options.outWidth;
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        Logger.debug("original image dimen: %d x %d", width, height);

        EventBus.getDefault().post(new ImageDimenEvent(mImageUri, width, height));

        return (height > width);
    }


    private Bitmap cropBitmapWithMask(Bitmap original, Bitmap mask) {
        if (original == null
            || mask == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final int w = original.getWidth();
        final int h = original.getHeight();
        if (w <= 0 || h <= 0) {
            return null;
        }

        Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cropped);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(null);

        return cropped;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeBitmapFromFile(String filePath,
                                              int reqWidth,
                                              int reqHeight) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath)) {
            return null;
        }

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
                                            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                   && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to take a look at Design patterns.
What you trying to achieve id doable using the Abstract Factory Pattern(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Here is a quick sample:

```
abstract interface IModelAsyncTask {
    public void action1();
    public void action2();
}
```

and the implementation goes like that:

```
// ModelAsyncTask1
public class ModelAsyncTask1 implements IModelAsyncTask {
    @override
    public void action1() {
         // Logic here
    }
    public void action2() {
         // Logic here
    }
}

// ModelAsyncTask2
public class ModelAsyncTask2 implements IModelAsyncTask {
    @override
    public void action1() {
         // Logic here
    }
    public void action2() {
         // Logic here
    }
}
```

and in your activity, just initialize:

```
IModelAsyncTask mAsyncTask;
if (condition1){
    mAsyncTask = ModelAsyncTask1();
} else if (condition2) {
   mAsyncTask = ModelAsyncTask2();
} else {
   // Throw exception 
}

mAsyncTask.action1();
```

Comment: All this method in MainActivity?

Comment: create new files for each class separately yo keep your code and easy to read and keep the last code part in the activity

Comment: What do you mean by logic in action1 () and action2 ()?

Comment: the code responsible for doing a task, like printing `Log.i("Action", "Hello I'm model 1");` and in the second class `Log.i("Action", "Hello I'm model 2");`

Comment: Sorry but the 2 models stay appear  on the screen at the same time

Comment: I think this related to Segmentbitmaps Loader .java s it is responsible for displaying the results on the screen

Comment: But I can't call or  insert the buttons click conditions inside SegmentBitmaps Loader